# Elasticsearch UI

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, solritas

I'm migrating from Solr to Elasticsearch and was wondering if there was a UI available that is similar to Solritas.  There is a great tool here:

http://mobz.github.com/elasticsearch-head/

Which provides browsing/searching capabilities, but it doesn't seem to have faceted browsing implemented yet (please correct me if I'm wrong).  Is there another UI that is popular with elasticsearch, or would I be better off implementing something using the extensive client apis?

Thanks,

Comment: why not contribute to that project, implementing facets and sending a patch / pull request?

Comment: +1 Mauricio. As a workaround just put in the faceted query and see the results ;)

Comment: quite suprisingly, I've looked through like 10 different UI's now and haven't found one that can delete documents.  I'm starting to think I'm missing something as no one seems to think this feature is necessary and its really the only feature I'm looking for.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 7):

Saw this recently. May be a good starting point for what you're looking for: https://github.com/okfn/facetview

Comment: This is a very nice jQuery Plugin working perfectly if you are interested in a solution for facetted navigation and searching.

Answer (score 6):

[Kibana](http://www.elasticsearch.org/overview/kibana/) is coming along nicely.  It requires a bit of customization to get it the way you want it, but it's built from the ground up to work with facets.

Answer (score 2):

There is no better UI available for ES as ES-HEAD is already great and steadily improves.

But maybe this is the perfect solution ;)

> "why not contribute to that project, implementing facets and sending a
>   patch / pull request? – Mauricio Scheffer"

Link to source: https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sense(Beta) extension of chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

[ElasticSearch data browser](https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/elasticsearch-browser)

Search, charts, one-click setup....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Calaca, it's a simple, yet good looking, search UI for Elasticsearch and with minimum configs required to get started. It doesn't support faceting though, but if all you need is simple search and browse, then this might work for you. On github - https://github.com/romansanchez/Calaca